# Removing exceeding column lines

Tags: tables, lists, itemize, multicolumn

Can somebody please help me remove the overlapping column lines?
As you can see in the picture below the problem only occurs when I
have a list in the right side.

```
\section{Bildungsweg}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11 cm}}
\textsc{10/2015 - 09/2020}& \textbf{Bachelorstudium Wirtschaftsinformatik}
\\\textsc{}&Einhorn Universität
\begin{itemize}
  \item Vertiefungsmodul: Mobile Solutions
  \item Thema der Bachelorthesis: \newline
 \textit{ ``Konzeption eines ganz tollen Algorithmus``} Note (\textbf{1,3})
  \item Abschluss: \textbf{Bachelor of Science (B.Sc.)} mit der Gesamtnote \textbf{2.0}
\end{itemize}
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textsc{10/2011 - 10/2014}& \textbf{Bachelorstudium Werkstofftechnik}
\\\textsc{}&Technische Hochschule Nürnberg
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textsc{09/2009 - 06/2011}& \textbf{Fachhochschulreife}
\\\textsc{}&Hans-Leipelt-Fachoberschule Musterstadt
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Fachrichtung: Wirtschaft
  \end{itemize}
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textsc{09/2006 - 07/2008}& \textbf{Ausbildung zum Fachinformatiker}
\\\textsc{}&Musterfirma GmbH
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an extra line that is added there but the extra vertical spacing coming after an itemize environment. You are right that it does not belong there. You can remove it by adding

```
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
```

after the itemize environment. (Or even reduce it further by specifying another heigth.